# Why am I getting an error declaring / assigning variables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to declare and assign variables on a Postgres 12.10 instance.

According to the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) I should be able to declare and assign variables as follows

```sql
DECLARE
  x integer := 1;
  y integer := x + 1;
```

but I get the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 2:   x integer := 1;
            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 13
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your full code?

Comment: That is the full code

Comment: Then that's no surprise. That segment of code alone doesn't make any sense and is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Ok great, can you show me what I'm missing please?

Comment: That is just a sample from a part of a function. Try using that in a full function code.

Comment: SQL has no variables, only PL/pgSQL (or other procedural languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code from documentation was only a sample showing you that you could use the value of a former declared value in a latter variable assignment and not meant to be run alone. You should use that in a function. ie:
[Check this DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oipEz8cR)

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  x integer := 1;
  y integer := x + 1;
$$
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: Updated my answer, try that.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I didn't. I showed that it didn't throw his error. The code is above it.

Comment: @Raya still, an image consumes much more storage than text :) Welcome to SO.